# How to pass an argument to a function within a customized function?

Tags: python, function, object, sampling, imbalanced-data

First of all the code snippet:

```
## Packages
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score
from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification 

## Create dataset

class_weight = list([0.90])

X, Y = make_classification(n_samples = 1000, n_classes = 2, n_clusters_per_class = 2, weights = 0.9,
                         n_features = 10, n_informative = 10, class_sep = 1, shuffle = True)

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.2, stratify = Y)

## Define Function

def resampled_fit(X, y, model, model_params, sampling, sampling_params):

    sampling = sampling(**sampling_params)    ## <= here is the issue

    X_train_balanced, Y_train_balanced = sampling.fit_resample(X, y)

    # Fit the model to the balanced training data
    model_obj = model(**model_params).fit(X_train_balanced, Y_train_balanced)

    # Compute performance metrics

    Y_pred = model_obj.predict(X_train_balanced)

    f2_val = fbeta_score(Y_train_balanced, Y_pred, beta = 2)

    return f2_val

## Define Inputs

ROS = RandomOverSampler(random_state = 42)
ROS_params = dict(sampling_strategy = 0.8)

SVM = SVC()
SVM_params = dict(kernel = 'rbf', probability = True)

output = resampled_fit(X, Y, SVM, SVM_params, ROS, ROS_params)
```

Basically I want to input 'sampling_strategy' as a seperate argument (for RandomOverSampler) in my customized function in the same manner as I input the parameters for the classifier object seperately. However it does not work like this.

I get the error message:

```
TypeError: 'RandomOverSampler' object is not callable
```

I checked the type of the RandomOverSampler function but it is `abc.ABCMeta` in the same way as the classifier object. What is the workaround to overwrite the input arguments of the RandomOverSampler within the function?

PS: Yes, I need to input the arguments seperately because I want to optimize the function with grid search afterwards. Obviously you need to do CV to use balanced sampling but as already mentioned this is only a snippet.

I would be thankful for any help regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed by inputting the functions 'RandomOverSampler' and 'SVC' without brackets.

If the input arguments are delivered with the function, then we can use the brackets, e.g.

```
RandomOverSampler(random_state = 42)
```

if we wish to input the arguments for it seperately, then we have to input the function as

```
RandomOverSampler
```

.